# React Context: TypeError: Cannot read property 'areResultsVisible' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Can someone please help me? I'm trying to pass data through context from one component to another (from Search.js to Container.js). However, I'm getting a type error. I searched many questions in Web, but haven't found an answer. Sorry, if it's childish problem, I'm new.

**Search.js:**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyledFormSearchBar } from '../styles'
import { data } from '../data'

const SearchContext = React.createContext()

export default class Search extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      results: [],
      areResultsVisible: false
    }

    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this)
  }

  handleSearch(e) {
    this.setState = {
      value: e.target.value,
      results: data.filter(item => {
        return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
      }),
      areResultsVisible: true
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <StyledFormSearchBar>
        <input type="search" name="search" className="border border-dark rounded" onSubmit={this.handleSearch}/>
        <button type="submit" value="submit" className="bg-warning border-0 text-danger rounded-right position-relative">
          <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
        </button>

        <SearchContext.Provider value = {{
          ...this.state,
          handleSearch: this.handleSearch
        }}>
          {this.props.children}
        </SearchContext.Provider>
        
      </StyledFormSearchBar>
    )
  }
}

const SearchContextConsumer = SearchContext.Consumer

export { SearchContextConsumer }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Container.js:**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"
import { StyledDivGridContainer } from './styles'
import { SearchContextConsumer } from './header/Search'

import Carousel from './container/Carousel'
import MobilePhonesDiscount from './container/products/carousel/MobilePhonesDiscount'
import LaptopsDiscount from './container/products/carousel/LaptopsDiscount'
import TabletsDiscount from './container/products/carousel/TabletsDiscount'
import Products from './container/Products'
import SearchResults from './container/SearchResults'
import MobilePhones from './container/products/MobilePhones'
import Laptops from './container/products/Laptops'
import Tablets from './container/products/Tablets'
import ProductPage from './container/ProductPage'
import About from './container/About'
import ContactUs from './container/ContactUs'

export default function Container() {
  return (
    <StyledDivGridContainer>
      <div className="no-gutters justify-content-between">
        <SearchContextConsumer>
          {
            value => {
              return (
                !value.areResultsVisible 
                ? <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Carousel}/>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Products}/>
                  </Switch>                
                : <Route exact path="/" component={SearchResults}/>
              )
            }
          }
        </SearchContextConsumer>
        <Route path="/mobile_phones_discount" component={MobilePhonesDiscount}/>
        <Route path="/laptops_discount" component={LaptopsDiscount}/>
        <Route path="/tablets_discount" component={TabletsDiscount}/>
        <Route path="/mobile_phones" component={MobilePhones}/>
        <Route path="/laptops" component={Laptops}/>
        <Route path="/tablets" component={Tablets}/>
        <Route path="/product_page" component={ProductPage}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        <Route path="/contact_us" component={ContactUs}/>
      </div>
    </StyledDivGridContainer>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Search.js** is in **Header.js**:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyledHeader,
         StyledSpanAccount } from './styles'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

import Catalogue from "./header/Catalogue"
import Search from "./header/Search"

export default class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StyledHeader className="d-flex w-100 bg-light shadow justify-content-center">
        <div className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around align-items-center">
          <div className="my-1 mr-3">
            <Link to="/" className="logo">
              <img src={require('../img/logo.webp')} alt="logo" className="img-tumbnail"/>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <Catalogue/>

          <Search/>
          
          <div className="d-flex my-3">
            <a href="#"><i className="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i className="fas fa-user-alt ml-3"></i></a>
            <a href="#" className="d-flex flex-nowrap">
              <StyledSpanAccount className="ml-2">Log in</StyledSpanAccount>
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="d-flex flex-nowrap">
              <StyledSpanAccount className="ml-2">Sing up</StyledSpanAccount>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </StyledHeader>
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Container.js** is in **App.js** near Header.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { StyledDivWrapper } from './components/styles';

import Header from './components/Header';
import Container from './components/Container';
import Footer from './components/Footer';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <StyledDivWrapper className="d-flex flex-column">
      <Route path="/" component={Header}/>
      <Route path="/" component={Container}/>
      <Route path="/" component={Footer}/>
    </StyledDivWrapper>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMsru.jpg)
[My folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcoiJ.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your Container component is not within your SearchContext.Provider. To make sure your code works correctly you must have your SearchContext Provider directly inside you App Component so that it is a common parent of both Search and Container component

Firstly, create a context in a different file

```
// SearchContext.js

export const SearchContext = React.createContext();
const SearchContextConsumer = SearchContext.Consumer

export { SearchContextConsumer }
```

Secondly, create a component which acts as a provider

```
// SearchProvider.js

class SearchProvider extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      results: [],
      areResultsVisible: false
    }

    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this)
  }

  handleSearch(e) {
    this.setState = {
      value: e.target.value,
      results: data.filter(item => {
        return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
      }),
      areResultsVisible: true
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <SearchContext.Provider value = {{
          ...this.state,
          handleSearch: this.handleSearch
        }}>
          {this.props.children}
       </SearchContext.Provider>        
    )
  }
}
```

Now you Search Component would simply be

```
// Search.js


export default class Search extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <SearchContext.Consumer>
         {({handleSearch}) => (
             <StyledFormSearchBar>
                <input type="search" name="search" className="border border-dark rounded" onSubmit={handleSearch}/>
                <button type="submit" value="submit" className="bg-warning border-0 text-danger rounded-right position-relative">
                  <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </StyledFormSearchBar>
          )}
        </SearchContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
}
```

Also no you can use your SearchProvider in App.js like

```
export default function App() {
    return (
       <SearchProvider>
          <StyledDivWrapper className="d-flex flex-column">
              <Route path="/" component={Header}/>
              <Route path="/" component={Container}/>
              <Route path="/" component={Footer}/>
          </StyledDivWrapper>
       </SearchProvider>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did similar with context.js, but I never knew that with Context API data flow also should be top-down.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to wrap your top level component with the context provider (`Search`), because the point of the context api is to pass the data top-down without having to explicitly pass it through every level, otherwise the context consumer won't have any context to consume in first place:

```
<Search>
  <App />
</Search>
```

Also, you need to use the prop `value` to pass the context from the provider, and not any prop (like `searchValue` in your code):

```
<SearchContext.Provider value = {{
    ...this.state,
    handleSearch: this.handleSearch
  }}>
    {this.props.children}
</SearchContext.Provider>
```

Comment: I've changed it in both files, but the error still presents.

Comment: What did you change in the other file? can you update your code? Also you sure you wrapped your App with `Search`?

Comment: Updated. I thought the point of Context is to pass data from anywhere to anywhere. Container.js is not wrapped, it's in the other folder from Search.js.

Comment: The point of context is to pass data **top-down** without having to explicitly pass it through every level, with that being said, you still need to wrap your top level component with the provider (`Search`).

Comment: I have another Context API in context.js and it works perfectly, but it just lies in global folder, passing data down to folder tree. Should I put Search.js up in the global folder too in order to use it?

Comment: I updated question with two code files and my folder tree image. Can you please check them?

Comment: Unfortunately, the entire way you are going about contexts is wrong, see @Shubham-khatri answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I got it!

Answer (score 0):

Import createContext like

```
import { React, createContext } from 'react';
export const MyContext = createContext();
```

this helped me.